# oracledb npm package NJS-045 Error with path updated

Tags: node.js, oracle, path, node-oracledb

I have installed the 'oracledb' package via 'npm i oracledb', required it in my project, and am trying to get a connection to it from my index.js file. I am running into the NJS-045 error:

> Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 8.0.0 (win32, x64)
>   Cannot load C:\Users\ZXR2737\Documents\EDQ.IECB.AnalysisAPI\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb
>   DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher
>   Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
>   You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.
>   If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
>   A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available.

However, I have already downloaded and extracted the instant client and set it up in my PATH as 'C:\oracle12\instantclient_12_2'. I even tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable which didn't help. I also have TOAD for Oracle installed on this computer which is the only other thing I can think of that could possibly be affecting this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have other (older) Oracle software that is being loaded first, giving you the message `DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher`.  Make sure the correct version is first in PATH.  Make sure it is 64bit.  Make sure you have the correct VS Redistributable (mentioned on the Oracle Instant Client download page).